# What happens when selector returns null (JQuery)

Tags: jquery

I have a code like:

```
$(selector).keyup(function(e){ ...
```

What happens if there is no element returned from the selector? Does it runs by every keyup?
Would it be better (from the point of performance) to write:

```
//Check if it's exists
if ($(selector).length){
  $(selector).keyup(function(e){ ...
```

Or makes no different?

Comment: jQuery handles the condition.

Comment: If the selector returns nothing then the event handler won't be bound. Simple as that

Comment: You are only binding function to an event and not executing the function. if no element is returned no function is bound to 'keyup' event for elements matching the selector.

Comment: Your second snippet runs the selector twice. So, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Akshey Bhat commented:

> You are only binding function to an event and not executing the
>   function. if no element is returned no function is bound to 'keyup'
>   event for elements matching the selector